# how an img or div can be fitted with a container that has vh unit , less than 100%

Tags: html, css

When I set the height of image to 100% it takes 100% of view port not 80%.
I used overflow:hidden for container that it worked but the image cropped and I couldn't fixed it with any options of img and css.
I also replaced img tag with div and set background image for it but I got same problem and image cropped with it again.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exbMVK)

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_582,c_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: codepen link giving 404

Comment: replace `height: 100%;` on the image container by `bottom:0;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif it worked , thanks ,  post it as an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `height:100%` since you are setting `top:30%`. Either consider reducing the height to `70%` to avoid the overflow or simply use `bottom:0` and your element will stretch to cover all the height whataver the value of top.